# Insert data in Postgres with XML-RPC

Tags: php, xml, postgresql, xml-rpc, openerp-7

I am trying to insert data into Postgres database by XML-RPC. Code for insert data in postgres database

```
<?php         
$customer_array = array('name'=>new mlrpcval('Customer name',"string"));
$client = new xmlrpc_client("http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8069/xmlrpc/object");
$msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($dbname, "string"));         
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($user_id, "int"));         
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($pwd, "string"));         
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("res.partner", "string"));         
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));         
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($customer_array, "struct"));         
$resp = $client->send($msg);         
$customer_id = $resp->value()->scalarval();     
?>
```

I am getting following error
 **"faultString Access denied"** 
 Does anybody know how can i solve it? 
 Am i missing anything? Your help is highly appreciated. ke

Comment: Did you send a login first?